# How can I make a table in MySQL called "order"?

Tags: mysql

When I make a MySQL table `order`, it is created successfully but, when I execute any query against it, it says `"error 1064 , syntax error"`.

When I change the name to `orders`, it works fine.

But I don't want to change the name. How can I execute our query against the `order` table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

can you use something like?

```
select * from `order`
```

Answer (score 18):

The word `order` is actually an SQL keyword. You would have the same problem if you tried to use a table called `group` or `select`. You can fix it in MySQL by using backticks around it, along the lines of:

```
select f1, f2 from `order` where blah blah blah ...
```

However, unless your table will only ever hold a single order (in which case it won't do so for long since the underlying business will soon be bankrupt), you should probably call your table `orders`.

That solves *both* your problems, the one you found and the one you didn't :-)

Comment: The SQL standard recomandation is to use singular for tables names

Comment: @Ben, if you'd like to point to the actual *section* of the standard that recommends this, I'll take it more seriously :-) Or did you just mean that it was common *convention* ? If the latter, I consider it a silly convention since you're *not* selecting things from a single order, you're seleting them from a tables of *orders.* That's the case even if you're selecting only items from one row.

Answer (score 2):

I got here because I was searching for similar solution for SQL CE. There using

```
`order`
'order'
"order"
```

doesn't work.
What worked was:

```
[order]
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed mine to, `CREATE TABLE ORDER_` (etc.., I cannot use 'orders' as I want each order for each customer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_name VARCHAR(255),
    order_date DATE,
    total_amount DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```

CREATE TABLE is the SQL statement to create a new table.

`order`: The table name "order" is enclosed in backticks (``) to indicate that it's a quoted identifier. This allows you to use reserved keywords as table names.

The table has columns such as order_id, customer_name, order_date, and total_amount. You can define your table structure based on your specific requirements.

PRIMARY KEY is used to specify the primary key column for the table.

INT, VARCHAR(255), DATE, and DECIMAL(10, 2) are data types for the respective columns.

Remember that while you can create a table with the name "order" using backticks, it's a good practice to avoid using reserved keywords as table names whenever possible to prevent confusion and potential issues in your SQL queries.