# unable to execute mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $con = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
     if (!$con)
     {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     mysql_select_db($user, $con);
     $ref='444';
    $name="x7";
$quant =1;
    $price=7000;
    $sql=  "INSERT INTO order(ref_id, name, quantity, price, status) VALUES      ('$ref','$name','$quant','$price','pending')"; 
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
```

This code is in php block. when i execute it i get this:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(ref_id, name, quantity, price, status) VALUES ('444','x7','1','7000','pend' at line 1

So any idea where i am going wrong? When I read the content of the table, it works fine thus proving that the connection and db is working fine. I am getting this problem whenever I try to populate a table. I am a Newbie in php and mysql :(. Please excuse me if the code contain a very silly mistake of mine :)

Comment: Hello, my name is using reserved MySQL words and it shot me in the foot.

Comment: i solved it :D thanks guys. i changed the name of the table for good and its working normally. thanks again :D

Answer (score 5):

`order` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you have to surround it with backticks `` like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `order`(ref_id, name, quantity, price, status)...
```

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a reserved word in mysql. It needs to be escaped using back ticks.

See - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO `order`(ref_id, name, quantity, price, status) VALUES      ('$ref','$name','$quant','$price','pending')
```

this also can help: [How can I make a table in MySQL called "order"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137910/how-can-i-make-a-table-in-mysql-called-order)