# how to run query on a table named order

Tags: mysql

I have a table named order in mySql. i cannot change the name of the table because of some reasons. i am having a problem in executing query whereever this table is involved for example

```
SELECT email FROM user u, buyer b, order p;
```

I have tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137910/how-can-i-make-a-table-in-mysql-called-order)  also but i am getting the same error

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"order" LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape the table name using `backtick`, ex

```
SELECT * FROM `order`
```