# error inserting data into MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, insert

need help please..

```
    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/posdb", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement dat = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO order VALUES('"+num+"',"+buyamount.elementAt(0)+","+buyamount.elementAt(1)+","+buyamount.elementAt(2)+","+buyamount.elementAt(3)+","+buyamount.elementAt(4)+","+buyamount.elementAt(5)+","+buyamount.elementAt(6)+","+buyamount.elementAt(7)+","+buyamount.elementAt(8)+","+buyamount.elementAt(9)+","+buyamount.elementAt(10)+","+buyamount.elementAt(11)+","+buyamount.elementAt(12)+","+buyamount.elementAt(13)+","+buyamount.elementAt(14)+","+buyamount.elementAt(15)+","+buyamount.elementAt(16)+","+buyamount.elementAt(17)+","+buyamount.elementAt(18)+","+buyamount.elementAt(19)+","+tot+","+tot2+","+(tot2-tot)+")");
    System.out.println(dat);
    dat.executeUpdate();
    cn.close();
```

Error message :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order VALUES('20130605093640',1, 0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9500,1200' at line 1
```

num is a string, tot and tot2 are integers, and buyamount is a vector of integer.

thanks.. any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137910/how-can-i-make-a-table-in-mysql-called-order

Comment: i didn't realize that order is a reserved words. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved word in MySQL -- use backticks around it:

```
INSERT INTO `order`...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: it still produces the same error with backticks. but when i changed the table into orders, it worked fine. thanks.

Comment: @user2453998 -- backticks should work (not single quotes).  But yes, I would recommend changing the table name if you can.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

In addition you might want to consider using a prepared statement the proper way.  This will help avoid sql injection and make your code easier to read.

```
private static final String INSERT = "insert into myTable values(?,?,?)";
public void insertData(String varA, int numB, Date myDate) throws SQLException  {

    Connection cn=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    try {
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("...your connection string...");
        ps = cn.prepareStatement(INSERT);
        ps.setString(1, varA);
        ps.setInt(2, numB);
        ps.setDate(3, myDate);

        ps.executeUpdate();

    }catch(SQLException sqe) {
        throw sqe;
    } finally {
        try {ps.close();}catch(Exception ex) {}
        try {cn.close();}catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```