# Unable to see table after creation in Flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying my hand in SQL alchemy and flask . I am trying to create a table in which i have a foreign key relationship with another table. Below is the entire code for application.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Member(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(30))
    join_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    orders = db.relationship('Order',lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Member %r>' % self.username

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    member_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('member.id'))

    member = db.relationship('Member')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now after importing this file and the classes in the python REPL i ran this:
db.create_all()

I can see the tables in MYSQL.

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_testdb |
+------------------+
| member           |
| order            |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I can even do a describe on the first table(Member):

```
mysql> desc member;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username  | varchar(20) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| join_date | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But when i try to do the same for table order it gives me an error:

```
mysql> desc order;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ord
er' at line 1
```

Can someone please point out where exactly the issue might be ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `order` is a keyword, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137910/how-can-i-make-a-table-in-mysql-called-order, this can help

Comment: offcourse ...how stupid of me. Thanks a ton.